# How to check if previous command asked for input?

Tags: shell-script, zsh, input

This question is related to this [one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337334/how-to-automatically-enter-tmux-copy-mode-if-the-output-isnt-fitting-the-screen/337340#337340) in case someone is interested.

I want to write script like that

```
$@ | tee /tmp/unique_name
if [[ "${pipestatus[1]}" -eq 0 ]]; then
    sleep 2
    tmux select-pane -t.0 \; resize-pane -Z
elif [[ $(wc -l /tmp/unique_name | awk '{print $1}') -gt $LINES ]] && [[ $(grep pdb /tmp/unique_name) ]]; then
    tmux copy-mode
fi
```

Checking with grep would be just a heuristic that works only for one language, so I'd like to avoid that and to know for sure that program asked user for input.